# Can't import the named export 'decode' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am using the html-entities package from npm and trying to import the decode method in my nodejs application.
I have updated to the latest package v2.3.3

I have tried plenty of differnet methods on importing, but none seem to work, all of them give a different error:

```
import { decode } from 'html-entities'
let result = decode('test')
```

This gives the error:

> Can't import the named export 'decode' from non EcmaScript module
> (only default export is available)

When trying with the code:

```
const { decode } = require('html-entities')
```

It gives me the error:

> This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'D:\giveaday\Give-a-Day\backend\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

And ultimately, I tried using the old way (v1):

```
import htmlEntities from 'html-entities'
let result = htmlEntities.decode('test')
```

and then it returns the error:

> ERROR  html_entities__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.decode is not a
> function

I've also tried the solution where they say to configure webpack by adding the following code in the nuxt.config.mjs:

```
config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: /node_modules/,
    type: 'javascript/auto',
  })
```

However, this did not work either. (the nuxt.config.mjs is located in my /frontend/ folder, while the library is being imported in my /shared/ folder)